# Unable to capture the query details using XtendedEvents C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to capture the entity framework queries via SQL Server trace using C# that are getting executed during my automation test run. When I run the below code ,I am getting the exception

**Issue**

The queries that are getting executed in the background are not getting captured. Any other thing that I can try to get the select /insert/ update queries that are running in the background

**Code**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = XXXXXX\XXXXX; Initial Catalog = Test; Integrated Security = SSPI"))
        {
            XEStore store = new XEStore(new SqlStoreConnection(conn));

            string sessionName = "abc";

            if (store.Sessions[sessionName] != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("dropping existing session");
                store.Sessions[sessionName].Drop();
            }

            Session s = store.CreateSession(sessionName);
            s.MaxMemory = 4096;
            s.MaxDispatchLatency = 30;
            s.EventRetentionMode = Session.EventRetentionModeEnum.AllowMultipleEventLoss;

            Event rpc = s.AddEvent("rpc_completed");
            rpc.AddAction("username");
            rpc.AddAction("database_name");
            rpc.AddAction("sql_text");
            rpc.PredicateExpression = @"sqlserver.username NOT LIKE '%testuser'";

            s.Create();
            s.Start();

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 15000)
            {
                s.Refresh();
                foreach (var prop in rpc.Actions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Description);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.KeyChain);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.IdentityKey);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Metadata);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.ModuleID);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.PackageName);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Parent);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Properties);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.State);
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Urn);

                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would test the queries in SQL Server Management Studio instead where the error message are much better.

Comment: Try adding the sql_batch_completed event (not all queries are sent as rpc events), and removing your filter to see if you see the additional queries.